# Android PDF page to image api

Tags: android, image, pdf

Is there any possible way to convert a pdf into image and show them on a image view?

Comment: Yes you can do this: http://andpdf.sourceforge.net Download it and in the code it has Bitmap of PDF. you just need to show it in ImageView.

Comment: Hi **Sujit** Do u have any sample code on converting PDF Page into image in Android 2.2. If so please post it i am searching for this from long time I have all libraries but doen't know what exactly to do to convert PDF page into image ... You would be very helpful to a team of 7 members if you does this small favor.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294833/2027232

Answer (score -1):

PDF isn't made up of images, they're vectors.

Tcouple open-source java PDF to Image converters though like:

http://www.jpedal.org/

http://code.google.com/p/pdfonejava/

Comment: i fear jpeadal and pdffonejava are not supported by android.. are they?