# How to convert Pdf pages into Bitmaps in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android can you please show me example to convert a Pdf file pages into bitmaps in android.

So, that i can display as imageview in android

Comment: What you want to do actually?Be specified on it.Post your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936194/android-pdf-page-to-image-api

Comment: i just want to display pdf within my applications. so that i want to convert pdf pages as images to display..

Answer (score 2):

I tried many PDF libraries, the fastest is [Mobi PDF Viewer SDK](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/). 
Do this:

```
public Bitmap getPiece(String path, String password, int importWidth, int importHeight, int piece_x, int piece_y, int piece_w, int piece_h)
    {
        Document myDoc = new PDFDocument (path); 
        myDoc. Open (path, password); 

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(piece_w, piece_h, Config.ARGB_8888);
        result.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        Page page = m_doc.GetPage(pageNumber);

        float w = m_doc.GetPageWidth(pageNumber);
        ratio = importWidth/w;
        w = m_doc.GetPageWidth(pageNumber) * ratio;
        float h = m_doc.GetPageHeight(pageNumber) * ratio;

        Matrix mat = new Matrix(ratio, -ratio, -piece_x, h - piece_y);
        page.RenderToBmp(result, mat);

        page.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this libary to did that

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

The instuctions are there, and is easy to implement.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is considered good practice to summarize the contents of links. I know you can't very well post the source code to the library, but the steps you followed to get the library working would be a nice addition.